# Guidance on naming methods that check data quality and then executes logic

Tags: naming, clean-code, single-responsibility

I'm writing boolean methods that do a data quality check and then performs logic. such as isRecordValidAndIsUserPrivilaged. these methods checks the record validity, and then checks the user's access )I can split each of these into 2 child methods to make the code more readable). I get that this is not following SRP, but don't know if it's ok.

Is this an accepptable deviation from SRP, and if so is there a way to name it better, so that it's easier on the next person reading the code

Comment: Others have touched upon this, but regarding SRP (and the underlying design principle), it doesn't say "stick all code marginally related to something into one place". If you dig a bit deeper, it says *exactly the opposite* - pull out the code that's not *directly expressing* the task at hand into helper classes or functions, give them names that are meaningful in the context of that task, and then let *them* handle those lower-level responsibilities. 1/2

Comment: Conversely, if the code is doing something *extraneous* to its primary task only because some other function/class/component needs it (coupling), see if you can take that code out and place it inside that other component (increasing cohesion). You get SRP (and, if you find good names, expressive code) by finding out what's the core thing about the function or class, and eliminating everything else. 2/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SRP](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/single-responsibility-principal-srp/) is about classes not functions. Functions are about [“one thing”](https://moderatemisbehaviour.github.io/clean-code-smells-and-heuristics/general/g30-functions-should-do-one-thing.html). So let’s talk about “one thing”.

If you think “one thing” can’t contain more than one thing then I assure you there is no such thing.

Even a simple function like addition has 1s and 0s being or’ed together and fancy carry logic. How can all that be one thing?

Because there is a level at which you can look at it and just call it one thing. One idea. One name. One simple meaning that hides the details.

The problem with your function isn’t that it’s doing too much. It’s that the name has failed to hide the details. It’s name reads like the implementations pseudo code.

Give me a name that tells me why I’d call it. Not what it does. Sure, the record’s valid, the user’s privileged, but so what? Why do we care? What does that get us?

If, let’s say, these were the preconditions to migrate the record to another repository then a good name might have been `isMigratable()`. Now it’s one thing. And we have a better idea what sorts of things do and don’t belong in the function.

If your thing isn’t one thing then you’re at the wrong abstraction. Find the abstraction that makes it one thing. When I want details I’ll look inside.

Comment: I agree about the lack of helpful abstraction in the name, but think that the SRP doesn't just apply to classes – it is helpful for all units of software at any scale, from individual statements to globe-spanning distributed systems.

Comment: @ candied_orange and @amon: I too think of SRP in a more hierarchical way, where you as the developer come up with some notion of what the "single responsibility" is within the level of abstraction under consideration. Yeah, in its definition (or, I guess, it's one-sentence summary), it's expressed in terms of class design, but the underlying principle finds its expression (perhaps in different guises) at different levels - e.g., your one thing / one concept / one idea at function level, or Martin's Common Closure Principle at component level.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful. I can't thank you enough. I see that this questions was closed... where can I more tips around questions like this? @candied_orange

Answer (score 3):

The presence of `And` in a method name is an indication that something might be wrong. It is often better to name methods not after what they do, but after what they mean in the context of your application.

For example, let's assume that your context is an ecommerce application. Is this code clear?

```java
if (isRecordValidAndIsUserPrivileged(record, user)) {
  database.insert(record);
  return Status200Ok();
} else {
  return Status401Unauthorized();
}
```

I don't think it is clear because this tells us nothing about the business processes. What does “valid” mean? When is a user “privileged”? Why is their combination important here?

If those terms are well-defined in the context of your application, then maybe having very implementation-oriented names might be OK. The following code might be perfectly fine.

```java
if (!isValid(record)) return Status400BadRequest();
if (!isPrivileged(user)) return Status401Unauthorized();
database.insert(record);
return Status200Ok();
```

But if the combination of these various checks has a business meaning, then simply picking a better name might clarify things:

```java
if (canIssueRefund(record, user)) {
  database.insert(record);
  return Status200Ok();
} else {
  return Status401Unauthorized();
}
```

Personally, I'd split these checks into separate methods. Of course, all of the checks must pass for an action to be carried out. But one aspect is a business-logic level concern (if the user is authorized to perform some action), the other is about rejecting malformed requests (if the record is invalid). These concerns have little to do with each other, so combining them might not be helpful. Things would be different if validity of the record depends on the user's privileges – that would have to be part of your business logic, and having a single method that checks this relationship could make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. When you say, "It is often better to name methods not after what they do, but after what they mean in the context of your application." How do you name things in away that they are still generic and allow re-use?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana Reuse is overhyped. Instead of designing components for (speculative) reusability, consider refactoring when you discover a recurring pattern. Sometimes two pieces of code look alike but shouldn't be refactored away because they have different goals. If you had extracted a function called `isRecordValidAndIsUserPrivileged()` then you can't really change what it does – you'd have to check all calls to see if the change is safe. A name like `canIssueRefund()` states a goal. If the business needs change, that single function can be updated so that it continues to achieve the goal.